# Retrieving adress from browser for my proxy in cpp (boost::Asio)

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, proxy, boost-asio

I'm trying to adapt a sample code of a TCP Proxy in order to use it on my browser.

Here is the complete proxy i use :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>


namespace tcp_proxy
{
   namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;

   class bridge : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<bridge>
   {
   public:

      typedef ip::tcp::socket socket_type;
      typedef boost::shared_ptr<bridge> ptr_type;

      bridge(boost::asio::io_service& ios)
      : downstream_socket_(ios),
        upstream_socket_(ios)
      {}

      socket_type& downstream_socket()
      {
         return downstream_socket_;
      }

      socket_type& upstream_socket()
      {
         return upstream_socket_;
      }

      void start(const std::string& upstream_host, unsigned short upstream_port)
      {
         upstream_socket_.async_connect(
              ip::tcp::endpoint(
                   boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(upstream_host),
                   upstream_port),
               boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_connect,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      }

      void handle_upstream_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
      {
         if (!error)
         {
            upstream_socket_.async_read_some(
                 boost::asio::buffer(upstream_data_,max_data_length),
                 boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_read,
                      shared_from_this(),
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

            downstream_socket_.async_read_some(
                 boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_,max_data_length),
                 boost::bind(&bridge::handle_downstream_read,
                      shared_from_this(),
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
         }
         else
            close();
      }

   private:

      void handle_downstream_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
      {
         if (!error)
         {
            upstream_socket_.async_read_some(
                 boost::asio::buffer(upstream_data_,max_data_length),
                 boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_read,
                      shared_from_this(),
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
         }
         else
            close();
      }

      void handle_downstream_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                                  const size_t& bytes_transferred)
      {
         if (!error)
         {
            async_write(upstream_socket_,
                  boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_,bytes_transferred),
                  boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_write,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
         }
         else
            close();
      }

      void handle_upstream_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
      {
         if (!error)
         {
            downstream_socket_.async_read_some(
                 boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_,max_data_length),
                 boost::bind(&bridge::handle_downstream_read,
                      shared_from_this(),
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
         }
         else
            close();
      }

      void handle_upstream_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                                const size_t& bytes_transferred)
      {
         if (!error)
         {
            async_write(downstream_socket_,
                 boost::asio::buffer(upstream_data_,bytes_transferred),
                 boost::bind(&bridge::handle_downstream_write,
                      shared_from_this(),
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error));
         }
         else
            close();
      }

      void close()
      {
         boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);

         if (downstream_socket_.is_open())
         {
            downstream_socket_.close();
         }

         if (upstream_socket_.is_open())
         {
            upstream_socket_.close();
         }
      }

      socket_type downstream_socket_;
      socket_type upstream_socket_;

      enum { max_data_length = 8192 }; //8KB
      unsigned char downstream_data_[max_data_length];
      unsigned char upstream_data_[max_data_length];

      boost::mutex mutex_;

   public:

      class acceptor
      {
      public:

         acceptor(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
                  const std::string& local_host, unsigned short local_port,
                  const std::string& upstream_host, unsigned short upstream_port)
         : io_service_(io_service),
           localhost_address(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(local_host)),
           acceptor_(io_service_,ip::tcp::endpoint(localhost_address,local_port)),
           upstream_port_(upstream_port),
           upstream_host_(upstream_host)
         {}

         bool accept_connections()
         {
            try
            {
               session_ = boost::shared_ptr<bridge>(new bridge(io_service_));

               acceptor_.async_accept(session_->downstream_socket(),
                    boost::bind(&acceptor::handle_accept,
                         this,
                         boost::asio::placeholders::error));
            }
            catch(std::exception& e)
            {
               std::cerr << "acceptor exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
               return false;
            }

            return true;
         }

      private:

         void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error)
         {
            if (!error)
            {
               session_->start(upstream_host_,upstream_port_);

               if (!accept_connections())
               {
                  std::cerr << "Failure during call to accept." << std::endl;
               }
            }
            else
            {
               std::cerr << "Error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            }
         }

         boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
         ip::address_v4 localhost_address;
         ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
         ptr_type session_;
         unsigned short upstream_port_;
         std::string upstream_host_;
      };

   };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if (argc != 5)
   {
      std::cerr << "usage: tcpproxy_server <local host ip> <local port> <forward host ip> <forward port>" << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }

   const unsigned short local_port   = static_cast<unsigned short>(::atoi(argv[2]));
   const unsigned short forward_port = static_cast<unsigned short>(::atoi(argv[4]));
   const std::string local_host      = argv[1];
   const std::string forward_host    = argv[3];

   boost::asio::io_service ios;

   try
   {
      tcp_proxy::bridge::acceptor acceptor(ios,
                                           local_host, local_port,
                                           forward_host, forward_port);

      acceptor.accept_connections();

      ios.run();
   }
   catch(std::exception& e)
   {
      std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Actually, this sample code need as args the local host and local port, and the forward port and the forward host.

I would like to edit this code in order to get automatically the host who is asked in the browser...

From my research i have to used the remote_endpoint() property.
The problem is i don't know how to implement it in order to "trigger" this function eachtime use ask for another adress on the browser...

I tried this :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>


namespace tcp_proxy
{
    namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;

    class bridge : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<bridge>
    {
    public:

        typedef ip::tcp::socket socket_type;
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<bridge> ptr_type;

        bridge(boost::asio::io_service& ios)
            : downstream_socket_(ios),
            upstream_socket_(ios)
        {}

        socket_type& downstream_socket()
        {
            return downstream_socket_;
        }

        socket_type& upstream_socket()
        {
            return upstream_socket_;
        }

        void start(const std::string& upstream_host, unsigned short upstream_port)
        {
            upstream_socket_.async_connect(
                ip::tcp::endpoint(
                    boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(upstream_host),
                    upstream_port),
                boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_connect,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }

        void handle_upstream_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                upstream_socket_.async_read_some(
                    boost::asio::buffer(upstream_data_, max_data_length),
                    boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_read,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

                downstream_socket_.async_read_some(
                    boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_, max_data_length),
                    boost::bind(&bridge::handle_downstream_read,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
            }
            else
                close();
        }

    private:

        void handle_downstream_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                upstream_socket_.async_read_some(
                    boost::asio::buffer(upstream_data_, max_data_length),
                    boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_read,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
            }
            else
                close();
        }

        void handle_downstream_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
            const size_t& bytes_transferred)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                async_write(upstream_socket_,
                    boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_, bytes_transferred),
                    boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_write,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
            }
            else
                close();
        }

        void handle_upstream_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                downstream_socket_.async_read_some(
                    boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_, max_data_length),
                    boost::bind(&bridge::handle_downstream_read,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
            }
            else
                close();
        }

        void handle_upstream_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
            const size_t& bytes_transferred)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                async_write(downstream_socket_,
                    boost::asio::buffer(upstream_data_, bytes_transferred),
                    boost::bind(&bridge::handle_downstream_write,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
            }
            else
                close();
        }

        void close()
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);

            if (downstream_socket_.is_open())
            {
                downstream_socket_.close();
            }

            if (upstream_socket_.is_open())
            {
                upstream_socket_.close();
            }
        }

        socket_type downstream_socket_;
        socket_type upstream_socket_;

        enum { max_data_length = 8192 }; //8KB
        unsigned char downstream_data_[max_data_length];
        unsigned char upstream_data_[max_data_length];

        boost::mutex mutex_;

    public:

        class acceptor
        {
        public:

            acceptor(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
                const std::string& local_host, unsigned short local_port,
                const std::string& upstream_host, unsigned short upstream_port)
                : io_service_(io_service),
                localhost_address(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(local_host)),
                acceptor_(io_service_, ip::tcp::endpoint(localhost_address, local_port)),
                upstream_port_(upstream_port),
                upstream_host_(upstream_host)
            {}

            bool accept_connections()
            {
                try
                {
                    session_ = boost::shared_ptr<bridge>(new bridge(io_service_));

                    acceptor_.async_accept(session_->downstream_socket(),
                        boost::bind(&acceptor::handle_accept,
                            this,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
                }
                catch (std::exception& e)
                {
                    std::cerr << "acceptor exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }

        private:

            void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error)
            {
                if (!error)
                {
                    session_->start(upstream_host_, upstream_port_);

                    if (!accept_connections())
                    {
                        std::cerr << "Failure during call to accept." << std::endl;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cerr << "Error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                }
            }

            boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
            ip::address_v4 localhost_address;
            ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
            ptr_type session_;
            unsigned short upstream_port_;
            std::string upstream_host_;
        };

    };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        std::cerr << "usage: EvilProxy.exe <local host ip> <local port> <forward host ip> <forward port>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    const unsigned short local_port = static_cast<unsigned short>(::atoi(argv[2]));
    const unsigned short forward_port = static_cast<unsigned short>(::atoi(argv[4]));
    const std::string local_host = argv[1];
    const std::string forward_host = argv[3];

    boost::asio::io_service ios;

    boost::system::error_code ec;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &mySocket = tcp_proxy::bridge(ios).downstream_socket();

    try
    {

        std::string str_IpDest = mySocket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string(); // Here i try to get the adresse but with this code, the adresse is seeking only at the begining...it's too earl

        tcp_proxy::bridge::acceptor acceptor(ios,
            local_host, local_port,
            str_IpDest, forward_port);

        acceptor.accept_connections();

        ios.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm doing this

```
std::string str_IpDest = mySocket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
```

But it's called to earl, i don't know how to trigger it each time user ask another adress.

I use boost:asio.

Anyon can help me please ?
The goal...After is to use SSL...but...after :)

Thanks a lot :)

Regards

Comment: Not even a little help or a little answer. Please, tell my why my post/question is bad...i need help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of protocol for communication between your browser and proxy. First your browser needs to send something like "connect to" message, then proxy should send info if connection was successful. I believe that HTTP has some headers specific for proxy handling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you're right, it's a TCP proxy, not an HTTP proxy !